# JMeter - I need to open and keep multiple websocket connections at the same time to be able to use them in parallel in JMeter

Tags: websocket, jmeter

I am using JMeter to test our websockets server API and now I have the following issue. I need to open and keep multiple WS at the same time to be able to use them in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

[JMeter WebSocket Samplers](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/) plugin provides possibility:

1. To open a WebSocket connection via WebSocket Open Connection sampler

   [image]
2. And then you can re-use the connection in the following Samplers which will be doing the real work: read, write

   [image]
3. When you don't need the connection anymore you can use WebSocket Close sampler

   [image]

The connections are established **"per thread" (virtual user)** so provide necessary amount of concurrent threads in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and make sure to specify enough loops or the desired duration of the test

More information: [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide)

Comment: Thanks Dmithri T !!   But if I close the primary thread group and start a new thread in the same test plan previous connections will close

Comment: Actually I want to keep my active connections throughout JMeter testing. Is it possible?

Comment: Set number of loops to `Infinite` and desired test duration. `WebSocket Open Connection` sampler can be put under [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) - this way it will be executed only during 1st iteration of the Thread Group or under [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/) - this way you will have full freedom to choose when to open the connection